# Selecting whole row in dataGridView with my int indexCounter

Tags: c#, winforms

On Form1 I have the int indexCounter which grabs automatically the primary key from a textBox.

How can I say the dataGridView1 on my Form2, that it should select the whole row where my int indexCounter is?

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
dataGridView1.Rows[frm.indexCounter].Selected = true;
```

^ This didn't work. I am working with Bindings.

Comment: pass the index variable into the constructor of your `Form2` when you create it and use it inside there

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. I create a `Form1` and set `public int indexCounter = 3`, then I use your 2 lines of `codes` without any modification to update seleted row in `Form2` and it works.

I think that somehow your `indexConter` value is 0, which will make the selected Row as `Rows[0]`. You may want to debug your second code to see the value of `indexCounter` at runtime

You did not post your code on how you grab the value for `indexCounter`, so I cannot test more.